# AWS Cloud formation - how to get public ip address for ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to create ec2 instance, and I want to be able to create a file that will contain ec2 instance public DNS name although in the following code I am getting circular dependency error caused by line:

```
"server_name = \"",{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "ECServer", "PublicDnsName" ]},"\"\n","\n"
```

Is it possible to get the public DNS name in the instance section when I am trying to create ec2?

```
"ECServer": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Metadata" : {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
      "configSets": {
        "Install": ["ECServerConfig"]
      },
      "ECConfig": {
        "files": {
          "/tmp/test.txt" : {
            "content": { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
              "server_name = \"",{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "ECServer", "PublicDnsName" ]},"\"\n","\n"
            ]]},
            "mode" : "000644",
            "owner": "root",
            "group": "root"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get public IP of the running EC2 instance by using simple curl command as-
1. SSH to that EC2 instance.
2. Execute following command-
`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4`

Answer (score 0):

```
        You can try using this, in CFT one cannot use the refer to the properties of itself using Fn::GetAtt function 
"ECServer": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
          "Metadata" : {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
              "configSets": {
                "Install": ["ECServerConfig"]
              },
              "ECConfig": {
                "files": {
                  "/tmp/test.txt" : {
                    "mode" : "000644",
                    "owner": "root",
                    "group": "root"
                  }
                },
                "commands" :{
                "test" : {
                  "command" : "curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname > /tmp/test.txt",
        "ignoreErrors" : "false"
        }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        }
```